# How can I provide global library references to my project?

Tags: typescript

I'm starting a new project using Typescript. I prefer to use dependency injection, but that does not stop me from having to import types for each injected value. There are things in my project for which I would like to have types implicitly available. I have been unable to find a way to make global types possible.

For example:

```
export class Greeter {
  @Inject('logger')
  logger: Logger; // Errors because my logger type is not available here

  hello() {
    this.logger.info('Hello world');
  }
}
```

How can I make the `Logger` type available to all of my files without explicitly referencing or importing the type in each file?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a .d.ts file with the type definitions you'd like and include that in your `tsconfig.json`'s `files` array.

Comment: This actually didn't work.

I tried adding into my `tsconfig.json` files: `"node_modules/@types/winston/index.d.ts"`. Using any exported interface from that file (eg. `LoggerInstance`) causes compilation `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'LoggerInstance'.